# xmlhttp response XML

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I am using `xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML` to get the get the response from the server. Does this require a while loop to make sure there is a response? If so, it wont wait that long and is there a better way to do it instead of this way?

Comment: um, no...there should be NO while loop. Show your code, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: so the method itself does not use a while loop to obtain the response?

Comment: Where do you see a while loop?

Comment: I was just wondering about the underlying mechanics

Comment: Learn about onreasystatechange, you can not speed it up.